# filename in tree entry contains backslash

Tags: git, windows-10

In our software development team, my teammate have used macOS and I'm using Windows 10. My teammate pushed some files that the name contains backslash (`logs\11132019.txt`) and then when I pull those files my local, I get **filename in tree entry contains backslash** error because in macOS, any files contain backslash character but in Windows 10 doesn't. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: The easiest solution is to make your teammates rename the file and push the update.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+invalid+filename+windows

Comment: @JoachimSauer you are right. Actually the other problem occurs when I want to run git checkout command that contains backslash hash or any previous version of that in Windows 10 machine.